# C# SQL command variable vs literal

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I'm writing a database CRUD application, and I'm stuck when trying to pass in a variable to the Database.  When I pass in a literal value to the database, the application works fine, such as the code below:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "Select * From Customers Where CustomerID = 'ALFKI'";
```

However, when I try to make a variable from the text within a textbox, the application will not do anythying.  It does not throw an error, it just sits idle.  Here is the code i used for my variable:

```
string searcher = Convert.ToString(txtSearch);

...

myCommand.CommandText = "Select * From Customers Where CustomerID = " + "'" + searcher + "'";
```

I've tried different CustomerIDs in the textbox.  I also tried re-arranging the way the single and double quotation marks are used, but to no avail.  Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks

**

Thanks Jon Skeet! Your method worked perfectly.  Darren, thank you for your input as well.  I will be brushing up on parameterized sql statements very soon, thanks for giving me another frontier to explore.

Comment: Be aware that this pattern is ripe for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.  Use parameters.

Comment: Forget all that. Use Entity Framework.

Comment: Don't try to quote the values yourself at all - use parameterized SQL. I'm somewhat concerned about the diagnostics of "just sits idle" though... and it's not clear why you're using `Convert.ToString` instead of what I'd expect to be `txtSearch.Text`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up guys but this will not be a distributed program, it is just a program I will be using to practice different techniques.

Comment: Oh good.. no need to code properly then... for practicing good coding techniques. ;)

Comment: parameters make your life easier, regardless if practice or not

Answer (score 4):

What you should be doing is using parameterized sql statement.

Try out the following

```
myCommand.CommandText = "Select * From Customers Where CustomerID = @CustomerId";
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", searcher);
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
string searcher = Convert.ToString(txtSearch);
```

Is likely setting the variable `searcher` to `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Foo`

You should use the text property instead

```
string searcher = txtSearch.Text;
```

Still you should do as [Darren Kopp Suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20386888/119477) and use a parameterized query to address a potential SQL injection attack. It also makes quoting easier